# Rice pilaff preparation on bbq grill

Tags: equipment, rice, grilling, barbecue

I've just bought a new BBQ grill ["Sunday One Tower"](http://www.sundaygrill.com/en/prodotti/p98-one-tower.html). I am beginner to grilling and now I wonder how to prepare rice pilaff on my grill. [I think I need a Soap stone with Frame](http://www.sundaygrill.com/en/a4-accessori-cook.html) and then place a bowler on it. Is it right?

Comment: rather than a pilaf, a rice dish that's easy to cook on a grill is paella ... but I have no idea about how you'd cook things on that particular grill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a regular pan on a wood fire bbq grill (even on a stone).

You can use a cast iron dutch oven (or maybe a Japanese cast iron rice cooker).

After that, you will need to keep control of the heat your grill generates at it can get really hot in a dutch oven.

Nice grill btw.